# Asterisk "Dial() Function" disconnect call when user account credit goes to zero

Tags: extension-methods, asterisk, sip

Hope you are doing well...

I have one more question for you guys:

How could we do in asterisk Dial() function, call goes disconnect automatically when user credit limit up-to zero.

Elaborating my question:

I want to create auto disconnection call from dial() function for the customer when there credit limit goes to zero. Running Call get disconnect when its credit limit goes to zero.

We can define credit limit let's say it could be 100 minutes for 1001 extension, if there limit goes to zero on running call ,it will disconnect on the same time.

Comment: You can limit the call duration using de L parameter in your Dial command. See entire doc at:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial          

L(x[:y][:z]): Limit the call to 'x' ms, warning when 'y' ms are left, repeated every 'z' ms) Only 'x' is required, 'y' and 'z' are optional. Numbers must be integers- beware of AGI scripts that may return long integers in scientific notation (esp PHP 5.2.5&6) The following special variables are optional for limit calls: (pasted from app_dial.c)

Comment: Thanks Sisco Casasempere ...............

Answer (score 0):

There are no way do that.

For single call you can use L or S option in dial command, BUT it will NOT stop call if other call used balance or balance was adjusted.